# VSCode Vetur Intellisense Not working properly for template register without .vue extension file name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

My orders.js file contains this line:

```
Vue.component("prefix-orders", require("./Orders").default);
```

My template file name is: **Orders.vue**

I'm using Laravel 8 at the same time for that project. But I dont't have any config file for. Vue or Vetur. Maybe I should create a config file for exploring .vue files for non-extension template registrations.

When I try to **"Go to definition"** right click on `"./Orders"` It pops up an error:

Unable to open 'Orders': Unable to read file '/var/www/html/xxx/Modules/Orders/src/Resources/assets/js/Orders' (Error: Unable to resolve nonexistent file '/var/www/html/xxx/Modules/Orders/src/Resources/assets/js/Orders').

When I change to `require("./Orders")` to `require("./Orders.vue")` it works. But my project has got so many files registered without .vue extension. I don't want to change my colleagues' coding standard. They use phpstorm and it works on it. But I want to switch VSCode.

Please help to use **"Go to Definition"** for require without .vue extension

Comment: So ? Why not use file name with extension? Most of the time it is better to be explicit instead of relying on (as in this case) faulty conventions...

Comment: @Burak "You should always use the .vue extension when importing Vue components, as omitting the extension creates numerous problems for static analysis tools. It was a mistake to allow it in vue-cli and we will likely disable it in the future." -- [tweet from Evan You](https://twitter.com/youyuxi/status/1288859415878283264)